# IOT controller for Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, pubnub, raspberry-pi3

I am new to the IoT world and would like to do a simple prototype to understand it better. My use case is to connect a IoT device to my existing Application.

I am looking at the following communication scenario:

Raspberry Pi <---> Server (which will run the IoT Controller) <---> websocket to my application backend running on the same server <---> Rest API interface between my application backend and frontend to control the Pi

To make the above explicit, Raspberry Pi through the network talks to an IoT controller running in a server. The IoT controller talks to an application backend running on the same server using websocket. The application backend and frontend communicate via REST APIs. From the UI I will control the Pi.

I googled a lot, but find the choices confusing.

It would be much appreciated if I get a pointer an open source or free trial version of a commercial IoT controller solution to experiment and understand.

Thanks

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully established communication between server and my raspberry pi using FAYE.
Faye can be used as a server sent event and is available for different languages. I used it with ruby. My raspberry pi client was also using ruby for this purpose.

https://faye.jcoglan.com/

https://github.com/faye/faye

I dont know about the open source software that does this, but with faye you can easily build one.

happy new year :)